# Clean string from array by distinct name

Tags: javascript

I have an array with a bunch of cars. However, the property `Model` contains unnecessary words that needs cleaning.

Here's the array:

```
const cars = [{
        Id: 1,
        Model: 'Transit 350 L3 Van'
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Model: 'Transit Custom 300 L2'
    },
    {
        Id: 3,
        Model: 'Transit Connect'
    }
];
```

Here is a list of how the name should be:

```
const cleanNames = ['Transit Van', 'Transit Custom', 'Transit Connect']
```

I need some sort of function that can clean the model string and return it if there is a match. My issue is that using `includes('Transit')` gives match with all and `includes('Transit van')` does not match any. Note: words outside those in `cleanNames` are dynamic.

How do I approach this?

Comment: Do you have complete control over `cleanNames`?

Comment: cars.stream().map(car -> cleanModel(car)).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: @Jamiec Yes. I manually clean the names. But I don't have control over the cars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change your `cleanNames` array to instead be an array of objects which match a regular expression to the replacement you want, it is easy enough to use that to match/replace the strings:

```js
const cars = [{
        Id: 1,
        Model: 'Transit 350 L3 Van'
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Model: 'Transit Custom 300 L2'
    },
    {
        Id: 3,
        Model: 'Transit Connect'
    },
    {
        Id: 4,
        Model: 'Test'
    }
];

const cleanNames = [
  {find:'Transit.*Van',replace:'Transit Van'}, 
  {find:'Transit Custom.*',replace:'Transit Custom'},
  {find:'Transit Connect', replace: 'Transit Connect'}
]


const fixModel = (model, replacements) => {
  var match = replacements.find(r => new RegExp(r.find).exec(model));
  if(match)
    return match.replace;
  return model
}

const result = cars.map(car => ({
  ...car,
  Model: fixModel(car.Model, cleanNames)
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This solution works nicely for me. Thanks @Jamiec

Answer (score 0):

You can check if all the words of a "clean name" is included in a car's Model with this code:

```
if (cleanName.split(' ').every(word => car.Model.includes(word)) {
    // This is a match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming cleanNames mean words without any numbers on it, for that you can use RegEX.

```js
const cars = [{
        Id: 1,
        Model: 'Transit 350 L3 Van'
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Model: 'Transit Custom 300 L2'
    },
    {
        Id: 3,
        Model: 'Transit Connect'
    }
];

cars.forEach(car => {
    // regex to match words that contain numbers
   car.Model = car.Model.replace(/\S*\d\S*/g, '');
   // regex to remove extra spaces
   car.Model = car.Model.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
})

console.log(cars)
```